# MvvmCross - Sounds / Notifications

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am currently in the middle of building some functionality for my app that requires me to play a notifcation sounds and vibrate, I've seen the tutorial samples with the vibrate but was wondering what the best way to play sound.

My initial thought was to use the messenger and get the UI to suscribe to that message and use a delegate to then fire off the method to play the sound. Would this work? I intend for this to be on Windows Phone, Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in a few "closed source" apps. In each of these I've implemented this using a plugin or using UI project dependency injection - exactly the same as in the vibration sample/tutorial - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n31-injection-platform-specific.html